# Не удалось найти имя типа или пространства имен

Tags: c#

Добрый день.

Пишу диплом. При сборке проекта появляется такая ошибка:

> Ошибка    1   Не удалось найти имя типа или
> пространства имен "MyLibrary"
> (пропущена директива using или ссылка
> на сборку?)   D:\диплом1\Транспортная 
> задача\Транспортная
> задача\lab1\Form1.cs  9   7   lab1

Пожалуйста, подскажите, в чем может быть причина?

Comment: Добавьте в проект ссылку на эту библиотеку. Правая кнопкой мыши по файлу проекта, в выпадающем меню выберите Add reference

Comment: я уже так сделала, библиотеку отправила в проект

Comment: Значит проверяйте импортировал ли  пространства имен и нет ли ошибок в написании. Это ошибка так сказать на внимательность, лучше чем вы сами, вам никто помочь не сможет, поскольку к проекту есть доступ только у вас

Comment: вы можете мне помочь если отправлю вам проект?

Comment: Выложите куда-нибудь проект, присылайте на него ссылку

Comment: извините пожалуйста за вопрос..может для вас элементарный,,, но я не могу как закрепить zip файл и присылать ссылку..можете подсказать

Comment: кидай мне на почту andrey_m_street@mail.ru

Comment: отправила, надеюсь получили

Comment: @RAIHAN выложите свой архив на любой публичный ресурс - Яндекс Диск, Google  Drive, DropBox и тд, и дайте ссылку на него/ На этом сайте возможности загрузки файлов нет

Comment: @RAIHAN: Поищите поиском по **проекту** (НЕ по solution!), определён ли в нём тип или namespace `MyLibrary`. В зависимости от этого разные ответы.

Comment: Проследите, чтобы библиотека и основная программа имели одинаковую версию фреймворка .NET.